Rotating each other row of spirograph patterns
I use the following code, modified from the answer to this post, to draw spirograph patterns;
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
% == begin spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling
\newif\ifspiroclosed
\tikzset{pics/spirosegment/.style={code={
\tikzset{spirosegment/.cd,#1}
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spirosegment/##1}} 
\pgfmathparse{(int(1/\pv{dx}+1)}
\tikzset{spirosegment/samples=\pgfmathresult}
\draw[trig format=rad,pic actions] 
plot[variable=\t,domain=(\pv{xmin}-0.002:\pv{xmax}+0.002)*\pv{nRotations}, samples=\pv{samples}, smooth]
(
{(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
 {(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
)
\ifspiroclosed
 -- ({(\pv{xmax}+\pv{xmin})/2}:\pv{rmin}) -- cycle
\fi;
}},
spirosegment/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1, dx/.initial=0.01,samples/.initial=21,nRotations/.initial=1,domain/.code args={#1:#2}{%
\pgfmathparse{#1}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmin/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathparse{#2}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmax/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}},
xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=2*pi,closed/.is if=spiroclosed,closed=false,rmin/.initial=1}%adding closed option to the pic, draws a line between peaks and centre
%
\tikzset{nfill/.code={%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myind}{Mod(#1,dim({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}[\myind]}%
\tikzset{fill=\mycolor,fill opacity=0.5,draw=\mycolor}%notice that it uses fill opacity instead of defining fill=\mycolor!40
},spiro colors/.initial={"green!60!black","cyan","orange","blue"}}
% == end spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.1mm,scale=.4,spirosegment/.cd,dx=0.1]
\path 
foreach \sclN [evaluate=\sclN as \scl using {pow(0.85,\sclN)/0.8}] in {.1,.8,...,10}
{
foreach \rot in {1,...,4}
{
foreach \clr [count=\Y starting from 0] in {yellow,orange,red,blue,purple,cyan,magenta,green!70!black}
{
(0,0) pic[scale=0.5,draw=\clr,line cap=round,rotate=\Y*90/8+\rot*90,  scale=\scl,line width=\scl*2pt]{spirosegment={domain={-pi/11.4}:{pi/11.4}}}
}}};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}

which produces this figure.

I would like to rotate each other row, so that the peak summits lie half-way between (not below) the peaks of the above row. I thought of using an odd even rule, but I do not know how to apply it.
To make it looks like this figure.

Or this figure


Heavy document that took me several seconds to translate.
Does the drawing method have to be retained?

@cis If it is possible. I apply this code for my spirograph drawings, which are too many. But I am open to any idea.

Here again, all you need to do is provide the angle of rotation ;)
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
  % == begin spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling
  \newif\ifspiroclosed
  \tikzset{pics/spirosegment/.style={code={
        \tikzset{spirosegment/.cd,#1}
        \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spirosegment/##1}} 
        \pgfmathparse{(int(1/\pv{dx}+1)}
        \tikzset{spirosegment/samples=\pgfmathresult}
        \draw[trig format=rad,pic actions] 
        plot[variable=\t,domain=(\pv{xmin}-0.002:\pv{xmax}+0.002)*\pv{nRotations}, samples=\pv{samples}, smooth]
        (
        {(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(\t)+\pv{p}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})},
        {(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(\t)+\pv{p}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*\t/\pv{r})}
        )
        \ifspiroclosed
        -- ({(\pv{xmax}+\pv{xmin})/2}:\pv{rmin}) -- cycle
        \fi;
    }},
    spirosegment/.cd,R/.initial=6,r/.initial=-1.5,p/.initial=1, dx/.initial=0.01,samples/.initial=21,nRotations/.initial=1,domain/.code args={#1:#2}{%
      \pgfmathparse{#1}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmin/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}
      \pgfmathparse{#2}\tikzset{spirosegment/xmax/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}},
    xmin/.initial=0,xmax/.initial=2*pi,closed/.is if=spiroclosed,closed=false,rmin/.initial=1}%adding closed option to the pic, draws a line between peaks and centre
  %
  \tikzset{nfill/.code={%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myind}{Mod(#1,dim({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}))}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/spiro colors}}[\myind]}%
      \tikzset{fill=\mycolor,fill opacity=0.5,draw=\mycolor}%notice that it uses fill opacity instead of defining fill=\mycolor!40
    },spiro colors/.initial={"green!60!black","cyan","orange","blue"}}
  % == end spirosegment setting with nRotations and filling
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.1mm,scale=.4,spirosegment/.cd,dx=0.1]
    \path 
    foreach \sclN [count=\X starting from 0, evaluate=\sclN as \scl using {pow(0.85,\sclN)/0.8}] in {.1,.8,...,10}
    {
      foreach \rot in {1,...,4}
      {
        foreach \clr [count=\Y starting from 0] in {yellow,orange,red,blue,purple,cyan,magenta,green!70!black}
        {
          (0,0) pic[scale=0.5,draw=\clr,line cap=round,rotate=90*(\Y/8+\rot-\X/2/8),  scale=\scl,line width=\scl*2pt]{spirosegment={domain={-pi/11.4}:{pi/11.4}}} % or +\X/2/8
    }}};
  
  \path 
  foreach \sclN [count=\X starting from 0, evaluate=\sclN as \scl using {pow(0.85,\sclN)/0.8}, evaluate=\X as \modulo using {mod(\X,2)}] in {.1,.8,...,10}
  {
    foreach \rot in {1,...,4}
    {
      foreach \clr [count=\Y starting from 0] in {yellow,orange,red,blue,purple,cyan,magenta,green!70!black}
      {
        (20,0) pic[scale=0.5,draw=\clr,line cap=round,rotate=90*(\Y/8+\rot+\modulo/2/8),  scale=\scl,line width=\scl*2pt]{spirosegment={domain={-pi/11.4}:{pi/11.4}}}
  }}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


In the first one, pic is rotated as before plus half the angle multiplied by the first (rows) counter.
In the second one, the angle offset depend on the modulo of the same counter.

And I confirm: compilation is veeery slow…

Thank you very much for your answer. Just one question please. What does this code mean. {pow(0.85,\sclN)/0.8}

It's part of your own code! It computes $\frac{0.85^{\scIN}}{0.8}$. And I guess it's what slows down the compilation.

Since the startpost method is "calculationally intensive", I was interested in implementing the 'Spirograph' with the decoration library from the TikZ-manual; more precisely with the decoration coil, aspect=0; which basically looks like this:

I placed these decorations on the edges of regular polygons (from the shapes.geometric library); this looks something like this:

Here: you seem to want 6 cocentric regular 32-polygons, decorations with 8 repeating colors; which are additionally rotated by a half of their central angle; or which do have an alternating rotation sense. 
So apart from the finer touches ("distribution of colors", "size of radii", "with or without fill-option", "negative or positive rotation angle" - what you can set all in the following minimal working example) something like this:

Or with some optionally fine tunings "fill=none, thick and no --cycle:"

PS-1: Due to the second picture: just add a minus at
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 (pos. rot. sense)

if you want the sense of rotation of your figures in the starting post.
PS-2: You can also say
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)

if you want an alternating rotation sense:

Alltogether: choose one of these three rotation angles:
% rotation angle ====== (\R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
%.... just comment in / out, what you need ......
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 (pos. rot. sense)
% alternative 1:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{-\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 2/3 (neg. rot. sense)
% alternative 2:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
% =============================

And, by the way: pdflatex needs a normal compilation time ;)
€dit¹: possibly alternating rotation sense added.
€dit²: 8 (instead of 7) colors corrected. 
€dit³: no factor ((-1)^\R) at 'rotation angle 3/3' needed.
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

% define wanted number of colors
\foreach[count=\c from 0] \mycolor in {green!77!black, yellow, orange, red, blue, purple, cyan, magenta}{  \xglobal\colorlet{color\c}{\mycolor}  }

\begin{document}
% Input: =========================
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{32}% polygon sides
% ============================
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{( (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (\R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
%.... just comment in / out, what you need ......
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 % rotation angle 1/2 (pos. rot. sense)
% alternative 1:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{-\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 2/3 (neg rot. sense)
% alternative 2:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
% =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C, ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B)  -- cycle %node[midway, font=\tiny]{\C} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Thank you very much for your answer. I will look into it, to understand your idea.

I edited the 'alternating rotatation sense' you asking for too.

Thank you for your edit.

Thank you very much for your concern and new edit.

Thank you very much. I think instead of making a separate alternative 1 ({-\R0.5360/\n}); it is possible to use the original code and using rotate=-\rotangle instead of rotate=\rotangle.

Sure. My idea was to make it uniform at this place (so that you have to set as little as possible in the main code). Other conceivable spirograph-designs (apart from the alternating rotation angle) basically all depend on a suitable rotation angle.

Please refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721163/spirograph-pattern-using-tikz-decoration-code-globally

As in the answer from NBur: The rotation can be achieved by replacing foreach \sclN [evaluate=\sclN as by foreach \sclN [count=\N,evaluate=\sclN as and replacing \rot*90 by \rot*90+\N*(180/(4*8)). This produces the following result.

Another solution is below which uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
The shape is obtained with the keys slices inner and slices outer to. The keys slices end and slices start are empty.
The starting angle is determined by the key start angle.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[looseness=2,very thin]
\foreach\n in {1,...,7}{
  \edef\r{\fpeval{0.2+0.05*\n}}
  \edef\a{\fpeval{35/sqrt(\r)}}
  \wheelchart[
    data=,
    gap polar=1,
    radius={\r}{\r},
    slices end=,
    slices inner=--cycle,
    slices outer to={\a}{\a},
    slices start=,
    slices style={
      \WClistcolors,
      fill opacity=0.5,
      draw=\WClistcolors
    },
    start angle=\n*(180/(4*8)),
    total count=4*8,
    value=1,
    WClistcolors={yellow,orange,red,blue,purple,cyan,magenta,green!70!black}
  ]{}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you for this amazing package!

@matexmatics Thank you very much for your answer. I will look into your package, and figure out how to use it.
