Spirograph pattern using TikZ decoration code globally
The following code from this answer, is used to draw a spirograph pattern, in 4 possibilities, with or without filling.
Is it possible, instead of repeating this code for every tikzpicture:
1- to insert the code globally, then
2- apply the desired possibility, only, in each tikzpicture.
Also, maintain the same curvature, with scaling down; instead of becoming more tapered.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\foreach[count=\c from 0] \mycolor in {blue, green!80!black, violet, brown!80!black, olive, orange, red, cyan}{  \xglobal\colorlet{color\c}{\mycolor}  }% define wanted number of colors
\begin{document}
% Input: =========================
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{32}% polygon sides
% ============================
%

rotate clockwise unfilled\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{2*0.25*\r*1cm}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (\R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
%.... just comment in / out, what you need ......
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 (fix)
% alternative
%\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
    % =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C, thick, fill=none, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) % -- cycle %node[midway, font=\tiny]{\C} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}

rotate clockwise and anti-clockwise\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{2*0.25*\r*1cm}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (\R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
%.... just comment in / out, what you need ......
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 (fix)
% alternative
%\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
    % =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C, ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) % -- cycle %node[midway, font=\tiny]{\C} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{2*0.25*\r*1cm}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (\R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
%.... just comment in / out, what you need ......
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 (fix)
% alternative
%\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=-\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
    % =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C, ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) % -- cycle %node[midway, font=\tiny]{\C} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}

zigzag clockwise and anti-clockwise\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{2*0.25*\r*1cm}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (\R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
%.... just comment in / out, what you need ......
%\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 (fix)
% alternative
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
    % =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C, ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) % -- cycle %node[midway, font=\tiny]{\C} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{2*0.25*\r*1cm}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (\R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
%.... just comment in / out, what you need ......
%\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2 (fix)
% alternative
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=-\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
    % =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C, ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) % -- cycle %node[midway, font=\tiny]{\C} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Seems you simply want a newcommand of the kind:
 \Spiro[<caption-text>]{<filled 1/0 ?>}{<clockwise 1/0 ?>}{<alternating 1/0 ?>}

and this is no big deal with some settings like
\newcommand\Spiro[4][my caption]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Settings ==============================
% Filling  - 1: yes, 0: no ==========================
\ifnum#2=0 %
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none, thick}}%
\else \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, }}\fi
% Rotation Sense, direction - 1: clockwise, 0: countercolckwise ===
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3)}
% Rotation Sense, alternating - 1: yes, 0: no ==============
%  see below ....
% ========================================


\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{capt-of}% optionally


% Define wanted number of colors
\foreach[count=\c from 0] \mycolor in {green!77!black, yellow, orange, red, blue, purple, cyan, magenta}{  \xglobal\colorlet{color\c}{\mycolor}  }

\begin{document}
% \Spiro[<caption-text>]{<filled 1/0 ?>}{<clockwise 1/0 ?>}{<alternating 1/0 ?>}
\newcommand\Spiro[4][my caption]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Settings ==============================
% Filling  - 1: yes, 0: no ==========================
\ifnum#2=0 %
\tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none, thick}}%
\else \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, }}\fi
% Rotation Sense, direction - 1: clockwise, 0: countercolckwise ===
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3-1)}
% Rotation Sense, alternating - 1: yes, 0: no ==============
%  see below ....
% ========================================
\centering% optionally
% Input: =========================
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{32}% polygon sides
% ============================
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2.00}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5*\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
\ifnum#4=0 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2  (pos. rot. 
\else %
% alternative:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
\fi%
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
% =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C,
% old:
%ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
% new:
FillStyle,
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) 
    \ifnum#2=1  -- cycle\fi
%node[midway, font=\tiny]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\rotangle}} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{#1}
}%% end of command %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
\Spiro[not filled, clockwise \& alternating]{0}{1}{1} 
\Spiro[ filled, counter-clockwise \& not alternating]{1}{0}{0}
\end{document}

Version 2: automatic texts

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{capt-of}


% Define wanted number of colors
\foreach[count=\c from 0] \mycolor in {green!77!black, yellow, orange, red, blue, purple, cyan, magenta}{  \xglobal\colorlet{color\c}{\mycolor}  }

\begin{document}
% \Spiro[<caption-text>]{<filled 1/0 ?>}{<clockwise 1/0 ?>}{<alternating 1/0 ?>}
\newcommand\Spiro[4][\CaptionText]{%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Settings ==============================
% Filling  - 1: yes, 0: no ==========================
\ifnum#2=0 %
  \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={fill=none, thick}}%
   \def\FillText{unfilled}%
\else  \tikzset{FillStyle/.style={ultra thin, fill=color\C!50,}}%
          \def\FillText{filled}\fi
% Rotation Sense, direction - 1: clockwise, 0: countercolckwise ===
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\Sig{(-1)^(#3)}
\ifnum#3=1 \def\ClockText{clockwise}%
  \else \def\ClockText{counter-clockwise}\fi%
% Rotation Sense, alternating - 1: yes, 0: no ==============
%  see below ....
\ifnum#4=1 \def\AltText{alternating}%
  \else \def\AltText{not alternating}\fi%
% Caption ===================================
\def\CaptionText{{\FillText}, {\ClockText} \& {\AltText}}%
% ========================================
\centering% optionally
% Input: =========================
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{32}% polygon sides
% ============================
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
HelpFigures/.style={draw=none},% set draw=black, if needed
]
\foreach[count=\R from 0% "rotation number"
] \r in {0.75,1,..., 2.00}{%% foreach 1 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\a{2*\r*sin(180/\n)}%  polygon side length
% segment length:
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\s{2cm*\a}%
% amplitude, if difference of two radii is 0.25 ===========
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{(  (\r+0.25)-\r*cos(180/\n) )*1cm-1.5*\pgflinewidth
}% ===================================
%
% ======================================
% rotation angle ====== (R = 0,1,2,3,...) ============
\ifnum#4=0 %
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*\R*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 1/2  (pos. rot. 
\else %
% alternative:  
\pgfmathsetmacro\rotangle{\Sig*mod(\R,2)*0.5*360/\n}% rotation angle 3/3 (alternating rot. sense)
\fi%
% =============================
% =============================
\foreach[
evaluate={\A=int(mod(\B,\n)+1)},% \A: start corner, \B: end corner
evaluate={\C=int(mod(\A,8))}% repeating color number
] \B in {1,...,\n}{%% foreach 2 %
%
% invisible polygon:
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\n, HelpFigures,
minimum size=2cm*\r, rotate=\rotangle,
](pol) at (0,0) {};
% Tests: =======================
%\draw[purple] (pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) node[midway, sloped, above]{\B-\A}; 
%\draw[] circle[radius=\r];
% =======================
% spiros as decoration: 
\draw[draw=color\C,
% old:
%ultra thin, fill=color\C!50, 
%fill=none, thick,    % alternative
% new:
FillStyle,
] decorate[decoration={
coil, aspect=0, 
segment length=\s, amplitude=\h,}
]{
(pol.corner \A) -- (pol.corner \B) 
    \ifnum#2=1  -- cycle\fi
%node[midway, font=\tiny]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0]{\rotangle}} % Test
};
}%% end of foreach 2%
}%% end of foreach 1 %
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{#1}
}%% end of command %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\Spiro{1}{1}{1}
\Spiro{0}{0}{0}
\Spiro[my own caption]{1}{1}{0}
\end{document}


Uf, I was confused with that many settings, but now it should be the right.

Thank you very much for your concern and time. Just one thing. Is it possible to  maintain the same curvature and height of the peaks, with scaling down; instead of becoming more tapered.

If I understand the question correctly, this results in radii that are no longer equidistant. Maybe, you open a new thread for this.
